# Yahoo Finance AutoComplete API Not working

Tags: ios, alamofire, yql, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use Yahoo Finance API in my app to get the list of stock based on search text.
Now the API is working in the yahoo console but not working in my app.

Here is the [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20pm.finance%20where%20symbol%3D%22%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20pm.finance.autocomplete%20where%20auto_complete_str%20%3D%22YHO%22) of Yahoo Console.

Below is the error I am getting from Yahoo.

```
{
    error =     {
        description = "Authentication Error.  The table pm.finance.autocomplete requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least APP is expected";
    lang = "en-US";
    };
}
```

I have created app in yahoo and I do have Clinet Key Client Secret Key but not sure where to use it.

Thanks for help in advance.